# Ubuntu 20.04 custom hotkeys to change keyboard layout

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xbindkeys

I'm trying to change Ubuntu 20.04's behavior in the following way: I want `Left Alt` to switch keyboard layout to English and `Right Alt` to switch it to Russian. I also want to keep all my `Alt+smth` hotkeys.

What I figured out so far:

- custom hotkeys: Ubuntu settings or Tweak Tools can't do what I want. I can use `xbindkeys` to bind `Alt_L` and `Alt_R` to any shell command but it breaks `Alt+smth` hotkeys even if I use `Release` modifier (like `Alt_L + Release`). I still don't know how to map anything to `Alt` without breaking `Alt+smth`.
- speaking of shell commands, the best I could do to change keyboard layout with a shell command is `setxkbmap us` or `setxkbmap ru`. This kinda works but ubuntu somehow doesn't see this: when I press the `switch language` hotkey the keyboard layout changes in ubuntu tray but actual layout is always `us`. Also `setxkbmap us` doesn't actully change the currently selected layout, it limits the list of available layouts to just `us` instead of `us,ru` which is a workaround but I could live with that I guess.

So the question is: how can I bind `Left Alt` to toggle US layout and `Right Alt` to toggle RU layout while keeping all `Alt+smth` hotkeys?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, while `Alt_L + key` is bind to something (likely so); would be annoying, if you could assign that key. The thing is simple if you try to set a hotkey in the `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`, probably the `Switch to next source` is set to `super + space` try to change it for your favorite key combination.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the clarification, I meant ubuntu 20.04, edited the question

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka thanks for your answer. The point is that I've used this setup on Mac before and I've developed the muscle memory to press left or right alt with my thumb to switch to the language I'm going to type in before I start typing. So it wouldn't be annoying for me if both `Alt` and `Alt + key` hotkeys are set. Also I want to bind keys to _select_ a specific layout rather than to _switch_ layouts. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Some inspiration here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316998/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-gnome-3-from-command-line

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do it using @vanadium 's comment and `dconf-tool`.

Switching language from terminal using `gnome shell`'s `eval`:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
--object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
--method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
"imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

Change the index of `inputSources` for different languages.

To set a hotkey you need `dconf-tool`. Navigate to `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/`. Conveniently you can't add new subfolders from `dconf-editor` interface, go to `Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts`, scroll down to `Custom Shortcuts` and add a new one. `custom0` subfolder should appear in `dconf-tool`'s interface. Set the command above as command and `Alt_L` or `Alt_R` as binding.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to assign desired hotkeys to `Alt_L` / `Alt_r` and keep other `Alt+smth` hotkeys working, but I was able to achieve requested functionality with less conflicting keys in `i3wm`, so my answer could be partially useful.

I added the following lines to the `.config/i3/config`:

```
bindcode Mod4+57 exec "setxkbmap -layout us,ru"
bindcode Mod4+58 exec "setxkbmap -layout ru,us"
```

Now `windows_key + n` (`n` has keycode `57`) and `windows_key + m` (`m` has keycode `58`) switch the layout to English and Russian respectively.

Note that it's required to use `bindcode` together with keycodes instead of `bindsym` together with symbols in `config`, because otherwise the hotkeys won't work in Russian layout.